# Random walk with variable steps

Tags: random-walk, random

A normal random walk use step $+1$ or $-1$ for some probability with barrier at $+n$, $-n$.

Assume a random walk with step $-1,-2,...-k$ and $+1,+2,...+k$ with absorbing barriers at $+n$ and $-n$ (the probability of steps are uniform $1/k$).

What is $P(k, n)$ = Probability absorption at $n$ with $k$ steps, starting with the + steps.
EX: $P(3,2) = 9/11$.

Comment: There are $2k$ possible steps, so shouldn't each choice have probability $\frac{1}{2k}$ instead of $\frac{1}{k}$? And what does "starting with the $+$ steps mean?"

Comment: For k=3.
One walk can be +1,-2,+2,-3,...
Each time the probability is 1/3
There is infinite number of walks
When the sum of one walk reach n or -n, it stop (being absorb).

Comment: You seem to be enforcing that the sign of each step must alternate. This is not a typical assumption when one discusses random walks, so you should explicitly state this in your question.